# i'm trying to flash message to user, but nothing appears in my website, what is wrong in my code?

Tags: python, html, flask

@app.route("/signin", methods=["GET", "POST"]) def signin(): #return render_template("signin.html") if request.method == "POST": email = request.form.get("email") password = request.form.get("password")

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Nowhere in your code are you flashing a message to the user. You're not even returning anything to the user when it is POST or GET.

See this https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/flashing/ for details on flashing